# javascript replace regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito hacer un replace en todo un string con un formato similar al siguiente:

```
var miRegExp = "^[0-9]+$";
var miString = $("input").val();
miString = miString.replace(new RegExp(miRegExp)+ /g, '');
```

El objetivo es reemplazar todos los caracteres no admitidos en mi string, en este caso numeros, aunque tengo otros casos que tomare a partir de este ejemplo para reemplazar otros patrones para cadenas como mails, nombres de usuario, etc

El ejemplo expuesto no funciona y tira un error pero lo pongo para que se entienda que es lo que quiero lograr

Answer (score 2):

Javascript tiene una notación explícita para crear una RegExp, usando `/` como delimitador en lugar de comillas. Después del delimitador de cierre puedes añadir los flags, como intentas. La otra forma es usar el constructor, que funciona de un modo más clásico:

```js
let re1= new RegExp("[aeiou]","g");
//es equivalente a
let re2=/[aeiou]/g;

console.log("hola que tal".replace(re2,"!"))
console.log("hola que tal".replace(re1,"!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

También podrías limitar el ingreso de caracteres no deseados. Defines el evento `oninput` (por ejemplo) sobre el elemento correspondiente al cargar *su* DOM. Para el caso que tienes entre manos (sólo números), el código puede ser similar al siguiente:

```js
var edadInput = document.getElementById("edad");

edadInput.oninput = function(event) {
  edadInput.value = edadInput.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
};
```

```html
<input id="edad" placeholder="Edad" maxlength="3">
```